# How do you load a swf file in webview from expansion file?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk-expansion-files

I some files that exceeds that playstore 50MB limit. So I looked up Google and learned that I can use `Expansion Files` to bypass this limit. I made the expansion file with my files and I can run the mp3 files fine using the `AssetFileDescriptor` by looking up some examples. How do I get the path to the file so I can set it in the `webview`?

I tried using `InputStream` but I was lost:

```
ZipResourceFil expansionFile = APKExpansionSupport.getAPKExpansionZipFile(this,1,0);
InputStream fileStream = expansionFile.getInputStream('flash/main.swf');
```

how do I get the path to the flash here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you load a swf file in webview from expansion file?

Adobe discontinued support for Flash on Android a few years ago.

> How do I get the path to the file so I can set it in the webview?

There is no path, because there is no individual file for the expansion ZIP entry. If you want there to be a file, you need to copy the data from the expansion ZIP to somewhere, such as on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: thats sad, will it be a naive approach if I download the expansion unzip the contents and delete the expansion file? Or do you know if there is a better approach to this problem?

Comment: @mrahmat: "and delete the expansion file?" -- I am not sure if you can delete the expansion file. "Or do you know if there is a better approach to this problem?" -- your more fundamental problem is that your SWF will not work on most devices. Beyond that, you could try writing a `ContentProvider` to serve things directly out of the ZIP file.

Comment: There's an [APK Expansion Zip Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#ZipLib) which allows you to read files directly out of your expansion file without saving it separately.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: However, to load that content into a `WebView`, you still need to copy it to a file or serve it from a `ContentProvider`. Unless there's some trick that I'm missing here...

Comment: @CommonsWare - yes, you'd want to use them together - APK Expansion Zip to get the `AssetFileDescriptor` to pass through your `ContentProvider`'s `openAssetFile`

Comment: @ianhanniballake is there a place where I can start looking into that?